# dojo Standby widget not spinning

Tags: javascript, dojo

Using dojo 1.8.1...Using the Standby Widget to show processing while the server is busy doing it's thing with an AJAX request.

I've created a dojox.widget.Standby object problematically and it works perfectly the first time I .show() or .hide() it.  The second time I try to .show() it, it appears but the spinner is not spinning..Animated .gif trouble??

How can I keep the spinner spinning when a button is clicked for a second or more times??

UPDATE....

What my app is doing is displaying data in a dojo DataGrid object for the user to select.  The selection are xmit'd to the server with an AJAX request and the server returns a file name that the user can download or open (.csv file).  I use the following javascript to create the open/save dialog on the client side:

```
  window.location.assign(path); //Open save/open dialog
```

If I comment out this line, then the spinner works on every click of the button.

2nd UPDATE....

Added hidden iframe HTML:

```
 <iframe src="" style="display: none;" id="ifr"></iframe>
```

When I received the path to the downloadable file from the server I use this to pop the dialog box and download:

```
 window.document.getElementById("ifr").src=path;  //Where path is location of downloadable file
```

Now, everything looks smooth for the downloadable file dialog and more clicks on the button keep the spinner spinning...

Thanks @Frode for providing the answer to this problem...

```
require(["dojox/widget/Standby", "dojo/domReady!"],
function(Standby) {
  var standby = new Standby({
      id: "standbyObj",
      target: "standby",
      color: "transparent",
      zindex: "auto",
      duration: "1000"
  });
  window.document.body.appendChild(standby.domNode);
  standby.startup();
});
```

Later when a button is clicked:

```
var standObj = dijit.byId("standbyObj");
if (standObj) {
  standObj.show();
}
```

...Server Processing AJAX request....

After processing completes:

```
var standObj = dijit.byId("standbyObj");
if (standObj) {
  standObj.hide();
}
```

This all works great but if the button is clicked again the spinner shows but is not spinning.

Other stuff:

css:

```
 #standby
 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left:50%;
   width:32px;
   height:32px;
   margin-top: -16px;
   margin-left: -16px;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="standby"></div>
```

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: No JavaScript errors.  It show and hides the spinner properly on each click, but the second or more times the button is clicked, the spinner is not spinning.

Comment: Can you post a full code example of it not working? It may be that there is something going on in another part of your code. Also gives the rest of SO something to work with.

Comment: I tried reproducing this, but couldn't.  I have a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/253Te/  Maybe it can help troubleshoot.

Comment: What browser?  Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: @Craig: Thx for the working example.  On my side, it works correctly in Chrome, Firefox and IE 8 work the first time with no spinning on second click.  Going to try using a dojo button instead of an HTML button.

Comment: @Craig: The following javascript line causes the problem: window.location.assign(path); //Open dialog save or open messages

Comment: I believe assigning a new location to the window will usually stop everything on the page. It doesn't strictly have anything to do with dojo. If you go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format and type window.location.assign("http://something/downloadable.apk") in the firebug console, you'll see that the gif halts. Not sure if there's anything one can do about it, perhaps loading it in an iframe instead would work.

Comment: @Frode Yep, just discovered that.  Everything works OK if I open a new window with the path to download..But, this looks sloppy.  I wonder how I can present a open/save dialog that doesn't look sloppy and won't stop my animated spinner .gif???

Comment: A hidden iframe seems to work pretty well. I managed to reproduce it in a fiddle, just replace the urls with a real downloadable file. http://fiddle.jshell.net/froden/Jb7Ar/ (uncomment the iframe line to see how that works.. seems ok to me).

Comment: @Frode That works perfect with the hidden iframe..

Comment: @GoinOff Excellent. Make an answer on your own question, and I'll upvote it for making me learn something new :)

Comment: @Frode completed the answer.  Thanks a bunch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is as follows:

Create in invisible iframe:

```
 <iframe src="" style="display: none;" id="ifr"></iframe>
```

When the server answers a AJAX request with a path to a downloadable file, display an open/save dialog box in the clients web browser by using the following javascript:

```
 window.document.getElementById("ifr").src=path;  //Where path is location of downloadable file
```

Not only does this look good, but the Standby spinner will keep spinning upon multiple button clicks.

Thanks a bunch @Frode for providing the solution to the problem.. 8)